# Why do I have to call() the push() JS function and re-set this to get the expected results?

Tags: javascript, object, constructor, prototype, new-operator

I´ve been reading into the [ki.js](https://github.com/dciccale/ki.js/blob/master/ki.ie8.js) source code and stumbled over a strange use of the [call() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (See `function i(a)` on GitHub). First, I simplified that `i(a)` function for my purposes, now the function looks like this:

```
function ki(selector, arr) {
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((el) => { arr.push.call(this, el); }); 
}
```

When I call my function like so: `new ki(".test", []);`, I get the expected result - an object with the DOM objects and a prototype property copyied from the ki() function prototype.
But, when I just slightly change the ki() function to this: (removing the, in my opinion unnecessary call() function):

```
function ki(selector, arr) {
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach((el) => { arr.push(el); }); 
}
```

Executing `new ki(".test", []);` will result in an object without any of the DOM objects, only with the prototype property inherited by the constructor.

This is what I don´t understand. Why is it necessary to manipulate the array.prototype.push() source code (replacing `this` with `this` in a different context)? Furthermore, will this code also work when used in strict mode?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ki function is used as a Constructor then the el objects are not pushed to the arr Array, but to the **this** value, which would be the created object

```
arr =  new Array
arr2 =  new Array

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((el) => { arr2.push.call(arr, el); })
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

first `arr.push(el)` can also be written as `arr.push.call(arr, el)`. looks familiar?

But `this` !== `arr` in your code.

In that Code `arr.push.call(...)` is used as a shorthand for `Array.prototype.push.call(...)`. Another common way of writing this is `[].push.call(...)`.

*Sidenote: wait untill you get to code like Function.prototype.apply.call(...)*

Comment: Thanks for the insights! I'd really like to mark both of the answers with the green check; The other one explained the situation, that the call function makes push() reference the created object and not the array passed to push() itself, a little better, but you've got my +1